# ClassCastException when changing AdView position

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the position of my `AdView` in a SherlockFragmentActivity (with tabs). As it is now the `AdView` is displayed on the bottom of the screen, I would like to change the position of the `AdView` so it is displayed between the `ActionBar` tabs and the fragment layout.

This is my layout with the ads at the bottom of the screen (this is working just fine):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admod_id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I tried to change it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admod_id" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This change causes a `ClassCastExeption` in the following line of code in the `onCreate()` method.

```
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
```

With this error message:

```
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.ads.AdView
```

It would be great if anyone could explain why this causes a `ClassCastException` and how I would be able to fix this.

Comment: Eclipse sometimes messes up res ids. Try cleaning your project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to clean the project after changing the place.